# Find and replace text in multiple files

Tags: windows-7, find-and-replace

I’m hoping someone might lend their time in helping me create a batch file or similar for finding and replacing text in several files.
I have tried many “search and replace” utilities but have not found something that does what I need.

The requirements are as follows:
Find and replace the SAME text in multiple files with different text FOR EACH FILE.

Example:

File1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt all have a text string “change me please”

for file1.txt replace text string “change me please” to “file1 changed” save as original filename (file1.txt)
for file2.txt replace text string “change me please” to “file2 changed” save as original filename (file2.txt)
for file3.txt replace text string “change me please” to “file3 changed” save as original filename (file3.txt)

Comment: This question would have been more useful if 'search files using wildcard' had been specified.

Answer (score 2):

Using PowerShell commands:

```
Get-Content c:\file1.txt | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "change me please", "file1 changed" } | Set-Content c:\changed1.txt

Get-Content c:\file2.txt | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "change me please", "file2 changed" } | Set-Content c:\changed2.txt
```

leaves me with the 2 files:

> changed1.txt
>
> changed2.txt

Could some kind person tell me how I would then rename these files and overwrite the originals:

> changed1.txt to file1.txt
>
> changed2.txt to file2.txt

Answer (score 1):

[Powergrep](http://www.powergrep.com/) can do what you ask.

Comment: thanks for answering, I had a look at powergrep and although I'm sure its wonderfull.. I cant justify the %159.00 price tag for the few files I would want to do every so often :(

Comment: Or download activeperl . . .

Answer (score 1):

If the files are not too big then you can use

```
$filenames = @("file1.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt")

foreach ($file in $filenames) 
{
    $replacementStr = $file + ' changed' 
    (Get-Content $file) | 
        Foreach-object { $_ -replace 'change me please' , $replacementStr   } | 
     Set-Content $file
}
```

Note the brackets around (Get-Content $ file) which means the file is read into memory (hence the requirements that the files are small), but this means that you the file is no longer in use when you go to write it back.

if the files are too big for memory you can write it to a temporary file and then use something like

```
Cp $tempfilename $file 
rm $tempfilename
```

to copy the temporary file over the original and delete the temporary file.

Answer (score 1):

I found an issue with your script.  Having $replacementStr = $file + ' changed' adds the sting $file to the changed file.  It should be: $replacementStr =  ' changed'

I modified this for my own purposes, but now the files names are dynamic, the string is changed correctly, and paths are not broken.

Don't forget to run this first...Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

Code follows:

```
$filenames = @(get-childitem -Path "C:\Program Files\Tivoli\TSM\baclient\*.opt" | % { $_.FullName })

        foreach ($file in $filenames) 
        {
            $replacementStr = 'New String' 
            (Get-Content $file) | 
                Foreach-object { $_ -replace 'Old String' , $replacementStr   } | 
             Set-Content $file
             Write-Host Processed $file
        }
```

JW

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -p -i -e 's/change me please/$argv changed/' file1 file2 subdir/*.txt foo/*.xyz
```

You can download Perl (for Windows) from [Activestate](http://strawberryperl.com/) or [Strawberry](http://strawberryperl.com/) etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use eclipse - simply load the files into a project, the follow the instructions on the following page:

http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-do-a-find-and-replace-in-multiple-files-in-eclipse.html?page=1

Basically do a search on the folder containing the files.  The results will show up in a search tab.  Right click on the file containing the files you want to change and select 'Replace'.

This will change all the files you want.  Added bonus of having your files in an eclipse project, which can be helpful in many different ways.  (Source control, syntax highlighting, unit testing, etc, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Open multiple files in Notepad++ and can find/replace across all open files.

Comment: Can Notepad++ be automated in a Batch file? If so, how would OP go about this? If not, this doesn't answer OP's question.