# For MacOS, how to delete text (long paragraphs) in multiple files?

Tags: macos, sed, find-and-replace

I'm learning Swift, and the *THE SOFTWARE Announcement* of repos on github  is too long.

It is very important. I have seen the content, so i think it's OK to not see it.

My question is how to delete the long paragraphs inside each `.swift` file.

> //  Copyright (c) 2014-2017 Alamofire Software Foundation 
>   (http://alamofire.org/)
>
> //  Permission is hereby granted, free of
>   charge, to any person obtaining a
>   ...
>
> //  THE SOFTWARE.

I think it's the same way to deal with `.m`/`.h` files of Objective-C.

This question is similar to the question [Find and replace text in multiple files](https://superuser.com/questions/322239/find-and-replace-text-in-multiple-files).

While the platform is Mac OS.

Many Thanks In Advance , :-)

**For example, Long paragraph is as following:**

```
// Copyright (c) 2011–2016 Alamofire Software Foundation ( http://alamofire.org/ )
//
// Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
// of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
// in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
// to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
// copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
// furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
//
// The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
// all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
//
// THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
// IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
// FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
// AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
// LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
// OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
// THE SOFTWARE.
```

Comment: "The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
all copies or substantial portions of the Software." That means **you leave it where it is** whether you like it or not, otherwise you are violating the terms of the code you are using.

Comment: Yes, I agree and changed my attitude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using search and replace is overkill for this. If the text is the same at the start of all your files you can do:

`for f in *.swift; do tail -n +20 < "$f" > "$f.tmp"; mv "$f.tmp" "$f"; done`

This uses `tail` to give the contents of each file starting from line 20.

But I would argue that you should not remove the licence text from those files. You probably won't be editing code anywhere near them, and they're only comments so have no effect on your code or compiled binary.

Comment: Yes, I agree and changed my attitude. And some comments are too long , so I have to scroll in every file

Comment: @dengApro Use the "find" menu item, or Xcode's jump bar to avoid having to scroll: http://www.stackoverflow.com/a/14540548/28290

Answer (score 1):

```
find . \( -name "*.m"  -o -name "*.h" -o -name "*.swift" \) -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file
do 
    path=${file:1}
    f="$(pwd)$path"
    number=$(grep  -n -m  1  "^[^\/\ ]" $f  |sed  's/\([0-9]*\).*/\1/' )
    if (( $number > 2 )) ; then
        num=$((number-1))
        tail -n +$num < "$f" > "$f.tmp"
        mv "$f.tmp" "$f"
    fi
done
```

improved based on @black_pearl

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode, Just paste words and replace it with white space

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Matt Sephton, I developed the following, calculate the last comment location count, then delete to it

```
cd $1
find . -name "*.swift" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file
do 
    path=${file:1}
    f="$(pwd)$path"
    number=$(grep  -n -m  1  "^[^\/]" $f  |sed  's/\([0-9]*\).*/\1/' )
    num=$((number-1))
    tail -n +$num < "$f" > "$f.tmp"
    mv "$f.tmp" "$f"
done
```